# How to include error message on login

Tags: redirect, login, errors

I am a novice with php, so I need help with this one. Please bear with me.

I want to include an error message on the wp_login.php page when visitors are redirected from a "user only/logged in" page. Below is the code I have for the page template which I use for "users only." It checks if the user is logged in or not. if he is not, he is redirected to the login page. This is where I get stuck. I tried to but together some code I found on google but no luck. Is there a way to pass an error message from here to the login page?

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) { auth_redirect(); }
add_action('login_head','ref_access');

function ref_access() {

global $error;

if( !empty($_GET['ref']) && 'access' == $_GET['ref'] )
    $error  = 'Restricted area, please login to continue.';}
```

Any code suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that you keep all code in your template file, which will prevent some of it from executing. Once you load your template without being logged in `auth_redirect()` will be run. This function stops the page loading and redirects to the login page, thus your `login_head` callback will never be called. Try dividing your code like this:

**your-template.php**

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action('login_head','ref_access');
function ref_access() {

    global $error;

    if( !empty($_GET['ref']) && 'access' == $_GET['ref'] )
        $error = 'Restricted area, please login to continue.';
}
```

While this will make `ref_access` execute on `login_head` it also means that it will run each time the login page is displayed. To account for this, you will have to find a way to let WordPress keep track of when and from where `auth_redirect()` is being called, and make `ref_access()` check for some kind of referrer. The first thing that comes to mind is using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store information about each ongoing redirection and clear the session data in `ref_access()` or on each new page load as needed.

An alternative option is using the `login_message` filter to display messages on the log in page, but the redirect/referrer issues applies there as well. Here's an example:

```
add_filter('login_message', 'wpse_87333_login_message');
function wpse_87333_login_message($messages) {
    $messages = 'Restricted area, please login to continue.';
}
```